# Check conditional type of key value within a mapped type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to do the following

*If actions property exist, and  callbacks within the actions properties that return string, then return X or Y.*

**Above code expressed:**

```
// type MappedType<T> = {
//   [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends () => string ? T[K] : never
// }

// it should check if object has property of actions, also check if properties within actions are callbacks that return string

type HasStringReturn<Options> = Options extends { actions: { [K in keyof Options]: Options[K] extends () => string ? Options[K] : never } } ? Options: 'Something went wrong';



type StringCallback = {
  actions: {
    test: () => 'i love owls i really do.'
  }
}


type FinalCheck = HasStringReturn<StringCallback>
```

Currently, it returns "Something went wrong" even though the type is correct. Maybe im missing something.

**I'm just trying to check for an existence of actions, and within actions check if the properties are callbacks that return a string. That's pretty much it.**

Is this where i have to use `infer` or just a generic conditional would be suffice. Curious to know. Thanks.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBcE8AcFNQLIENpwCYBUawDwYHygC8oA3gFAijUDaA0qAJYB2oA1rJAPYBmoGAXQBc-egNCwAHuFjM0AZ1AAKAJTFC88ACcWAc1AB%20UXXEjmsAG6wtlMAF9ytpuFDyAFlwCuAGzSgAxm6w-mxMfFwARgBWwS5uSIrQWlxwWlCgvKBI-uCMXMzyADRZ3vJcAUEhYaBJKda5sIoA7ozgbixZOXkFWVrw-kje3hHZbIptSC594J5arJo6zLqOUHCgABIJAMraegBKsDNzOADy0Ln58oQkZxc9UjJyiqSdd-IiL-RMrBzcfLfdeTCUAAy5iCTSWQKZRqIgaXZLQwg86A8FmSzWUB2LFI0EFEQAci2XAAtod2oimrIXE1kksCQBuRwrbCgHaLXQAYUGw1GxDI5Go2TeH0F1AgjXAIlU6lABMYoG8XCsGSapSYoD6PMgoDQXAAdASxQ4HCy1gAxFiDTmVUIkTbydn7Q6zZg4J1LblDEYhfDM8hAA)

Comment: You're checking at the wrong level; you can try [this](https://tsplay.dev/N7GoPN) to fix it. Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: This looks good :) this works. Curious, how would you go about producing a red swiggly if something went wrong happend ? I tried using never, but it doesn't produce a swiggly red error. Swiggly Red as in a typescript error, not assignable to never. That kind of error.

Comment: Are you trying to ask a followup question here, or was that part of your original issue?  You could do [this](https://tsplay.dev/NrEX5w) but it seems out of scope here.  Should I write up my original answer or do you need this included?

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what im looking for, you could include it in your answer if you want, but its no biggie. I really appreciate this. Will accept your answer, whenever its up, thanks man :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your version is that you are checking `Options`, not `Options["actions"]` for the function properties.  You'll need to push your analysis down one level, possibly by using [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to give a type parameter name to `Options["actions"]`, as shown here:

```
type HasStringReturn<T> =
  T extends { actions: infer A } ?
  A extends { [K in keyof A]: A[K] extends () => string ? A[K] : never } ? T :
  "something went wrong" :
  "something continued to go wrong";
```

(Note I've changed `Options` to `T` to be more in line with type parameter naming conventions, but you can do it however you want).  Notice that this is a pair of checks, each one of which can fail and result in the error condition.  First we check if `T` has an `actions` property, and then we check if that `actions` property is of the right type.

Let's make sure it behaves as expected:

```
type StringCallback = {
  actions: {
    test: () => 'i love owls i really do.',
  }
}
type Good = HasStringReturn<StringCallback>
/* type Good = {
    actions: {
        test: () => 'i love owls i really do.';
    };
} */

type BadStringCallback = {
  actions: {
    test: () => 'i love owls i really do.',
    oops: number
  }
}
type Bad = HasStringReturn<BadStringCallback>;
// type Bad = "something went wrong"

type ReallyBadStringCallback = { test(): string }
type ReallyBad = HasStringReturn<ReallyBadStringCallback>;
// type ReallyBad = "something continued to go wrong"
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAEgQwM4GUQCcCWA7A5gJShAFd1sAeAFQD4YBeYGGSmKADxCmwBMkYBvGAgDGITAHtsSAFwwcAMyjoYAQRgBfGAH5Gq1hy68BMANoBpOdhgBrKGHHzVAXVkrzT-Zx58AFAEp6WiQMHFxtVXcYWWwoADclDXCWaV0AIiRxAFsiAAtQmAB3LhBC9ElcVKi0jOyQPLwYYUkxbGIobhgQcRhcboKyvFSAbmBQSFg0LDwAYQQAGzmAIxFregFdETFJGXWmJk5g2X9AmAByTBg58XiYcQK5vgv0KHm5sBhucQA6U4AaXXUwEB4GgMAA4uJxB06PBkJNQoQSGRyPCZq9lsJrNRgAB6ABUnXG4Mh0N2e02Eiksn4uj2ewOICOATotHOl2usDuDzkMGer3enx+Izp6hGmjxONGINgACEENxUbhZgsMasYTSmBTttTaZ0oIcYMcWWcLlcblzHryXgsBd8-rrIRAdq1MoslACgWNQXLSYhUCE8IjSBQfYrlUsVtQRjicYTvfK1uksrl8kVsCV+uVUlKiYR+aGA0r0Ss1oIGf5ZMEpmFgbnrW8fWs-Yqg8i8zaC9Xw6qo7jY9KYO2GwmYUnavUwk10zg2h0uj0+gMKjnQQAxHDzaY5KCY8i6FjsLxGZuF1sUMPFzG0GEXlUrYDXmCxcSYbgjUZAA)

Answer (score 0):

To address the issue in your TypeScript code, it's important to define the type constraints in your conditional type correctly. The main goal here is to check if an object has an actions property and if all properties within actions are functions that return a string. Here's how you can modify your HasStringReturn type:

```
type HasStringReturn<Options> = 
  Options extends { actions: infer Actions } 
  ? { [K in keyof Actions]: Actions[K] extends () => string ? Actions[K] : never } extends Actions
    ? Options 
    : 'Something went wrong'
  : 'Something went wrong';
```

Explanation:

`Options extends { actions: infer Actions } ? ... : 'Something went wrong'`: This checks if Options has an actions property and infers the type of actions.

`{ [K in keyof Actions]: Actions[K] extends () => string ? Actions[K] : never }` extends Actions ? Options : 'Something went wrong': This part maps over each key in Actions and checks if the type of the property is a function returning a string. If all properties in Actions match this condition, the original Options type is returned; otherwise, it returns 'Something went wrong'.

With this approach, your FinalCheck type will evaluate correctly based on whether the conditions are met in the StringCallback type.

Let's test it with your StringCallback type:

```
type StringCallback = {
  actions: {
    test: () => 'i love owls i really do.'
  }
}

type FinalCheck = HasStringReturn<StringCallback>
```

In this case, FinalCheck should correctly resolve to StringCallback since the actions property exists and its test property is a callback returning a string.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy